# How does the Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location interact with the mind spike spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The amulet of proof against detection and location (APADL) states that:

> Whilst wearing this amulet you are hidden from divination magic. You can’t be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors

When the DMG was written, to the best of my knowledge, there were no divination spells capable of dealing damage so this wouldn’t have been an issue at the time. With the introduction of XGE we now have the Mind Spike spell which is both divination and deals damage and which specifically states that:

> You reach into the mind of one creature you can see within range. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw, taking 3d8 damage on a failed save or half as much on a successful one.

Given this, whilst I don’t think that the amulet was designed to prevent damage, (it is only uncommon after all) would it do so?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## It would prevent the spell from targeting you

Consider the wording of the amulet:

> Whilst wearing this amulet you are hidden from [school] magic. You can't be targeted by such magic [...]

If we were to replace [school] with evocation, it'd be pretty clear by the description that you can't be targeted by evocation magic. I think it's equally clear in the case of divination.

Additionally, this amulet is of uncommon rarity. Blocking damage from a narrow range of spells is not unusually powerful for an uncommon magic item. A few examples of uncommon magic items that block spells:

- **Brooch of Shielding**: This gives resistance to force damage, and entirely negates Magic Missile (which is, in my experience, much more common than Mind Spike).
- **Periapt of Health**: This amulet blocks any spells that cause a disease in the target.
- **Necklace of Adaptation**: This necklace gives advantage to saving throws made against harmful gases such as Cloudkill and Stinking Cloud effects, as well as inhaled poison and some dragon breath weapons.

All of those effects are much stronger than Mind Spike.

Answer (score 10):

## The amulet can't prevent damage, but it will prevent Mind Spike from being cast on you in the first place

The amulet won't prevent its wearer from being damaged by a divination spell. But it will prevent its wearer from being *targeted* by divination spells, including by divination spells that deal damage.

The amulet's description is quite clear:

> Whilst wearing this amulet you are hidden from divination magic. You can’t be targeted by such magic [...]

So anything that is "divination magic", which definitely includes divination spells of all kinds, can't be targeted on the wearer of the amulet. This includes (for example) *Mind Spike*, *Scrying*, and *Hunter's Mark*.

*Hunter's Mark* is especially interesting here, because while it can't target the wearer of an amulet, it can damage them. If someone casts *Hunter's Mark* on you, and then you put on an amulet, you'll still take extra damage from *Hunter's Mark* when they attack you. This is, obviously, a very niche case, but I hope it demonstrates the important distinction that "targeting" implies.

Comment: Another example would be spells that do damage without the need of targeting.  Say for example, if Fireball was a divination spell, it deals damage to creatures within a specified area.  The amulet would not protect you in this case, because you haven't been targeted, you've instead found yourself within an area of effect.

Comment: @DoctorJones That was going to be part of the answer, but the wording around AoE spells makes it a bit less clear cut than I'd like, and there's no divination spells in that category anyway.